# Angular data parsing string for multiple numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, parsing, numbers

I have an array of objects coming back in my data and I need to loop through each of them and parse out specific numbers.

Here's what one of the objects looks like.
    Object 
    {
    reportId: 13, 
    reportName: "Testing", 
    acceptableFlag: "N/A", 
    whereClause: "where filter_5_id = '50001' and filter_12_id = 120087  order by tr.test_result_id null"
    }

Basically I need to get this whereClause field and parse through it and extract these 5 digit ids, for some reason some of them will have a single quote on it, and the other will be as you see the 120087. Also if there is a second one, it could also be wrapped in parantheses, (120087) like this. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Angular by itself cannot handle SQL statements on it's own. Angular doesn't understand the where clause. You may have better luck integrating a library that understands this kind of sql like syntax. You may have some luck with [BreezeJS](http://breeze.github.io/doc-main/index.html), for example..

```
// query with parameters
var query = EntityQuery.from("CustomersWhoPurchasedProducts")
    .withParameters({ 
        zipCode: 90210, 
        startDate: new Date(2014, 1, 1).toISOString(), 
        endDate: new Date(2014, 4, 1).toISOString(),
        productIds: [911, 928, 935, 944] 
    });

// Add filtering
query = query.where('CompanyName', 'startsWith', 'A');
// Add paging
query = query.skip(20).take(10);
```

you would parse out the field in question, I.E `Where` `StartsWith` etc into the query filter and query using this SQL, Linq approach

Comment: well it's just a string coming back, i don't need it to execute any sql or anything

Comment: then you are going to have to parse the string into it's important components